# Zend_Form - add CSS Class :: How can I add css class to label in Zend_Form?

Tags: css, zend-framework, label, zend-form

How can I add css class to label in Zend_Form?

**This is html way**:

```
<dt><label for="foo" class="label-design">Foo</label></dt>
```

**How can I write above row with Zend_Form**?

(I know how to write label but i dont know how can i add ccss class.

```
$model = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('model');
$model->setLabel('Model');
```

)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add class to dt element, not to label:

```
$model->addDecorator(
    new Zend_Form_Decorator_Label(array('tag' => 'dt', 'class' => 'label-design'))
);
```

And then just modify your CSS selector from label.label-design to dt.label-design label

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add a class directly to the label. Here is an awesome article from Matthew Weier O'Phinney describing all about decorators: http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/.

To answer your question, I would do it like this:

```
$model->setLabel("Model")
      ->setDecorators(array(array("Label",array("class"=>"full")),"ViewHelper"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly add the class 'label-design' to the label of your element $model:

```
$model->addDecorator('Label', ['class' => 'label-design']);
```