# Zend Framework. How to add extra class to label

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

My problem is after the form has been generated, the label class has assigned to a default which is optional and the html code looks like this:

```
<div class="form_wrapper">
    <label for="email" class="optional">Username(e-mail):</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
</div>
```

My zend code inside action is:

```
$form->addElement('text', 'email');
$usernameElement = $form->getElement('email');
$usernameElement->setLabel('Username(e-mail):');
$usernameElement->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Label',
    new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag' => 'div','class'=>'form_wrapper')) 
));
```

But in some case, I want it to be set as a different value that I can easily style in css. The html code I want is this(get rid of "optional"):

```
<div class="form_wrapper">
    <label for="email" class="email_label">Username(e-mail):</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this similar question:

[Zend_Form - add CSS Class :: How can I add css class to label in Zend_Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157058/zend-form-add-css-class-how-can-i-add-css-class-to-label-in-zend-form)

Adding a class to the form element itself is as simple as:

```
$usernameElement->class = 'email_label';
```

It appears that if you want to set the class on the label though, you'll want to add a `Zend_Form_Decorator_Label` and pass in the classname.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is ZF1, I dug this out the reference for 1.12.3:

```
$form->getElement('elementname')
    ->setDecorators(array(
         array('ViewHelper',
               array('helper' => 'formText')),
         array('Label',
               array('class' => 'another'))
    ));
```

The above provides you with an additional class.  So you'll get something like:

```
<label for="elementname" class="another optional">Your Label Text</label>
```

OR

```
<label for="elementname" class="another required">Your Label Text</label>
```